# How can I call a variable outside of the function it was created in?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Essentially I have this little code snippet, and this has been a recurring problem for me, (the error message is displayed) I'm creating a button inside of a function, but when I try to add an event listener to it later it doesn't work, (and I understand why it doesn't work).

I've tried to initiate the variable linked to the button outside of the function just like.

`var newListItemBtn;`

But then it tells me can't add event listener to undefined variable. (which I also understand why.)

if I try to initiate the variable with the code

`var newListItemBtn = document.createElement('button');`

it creates the button when the code runs, and not when the function is called, so it replaces the button in the new list.

How can I make it to where I can call the variable outside of the function and add an eventlistener to it??

```js
var createListBtn = document.getElementById('createListBtn'),
    listArea = document.getElementById('listArea');

function createList(){
    var list = document.createElement('ul'),
        newListItemBtn = document.createElement('button');
    
    newListItemBtn.classList.add ('newListItemBtn');
    newListItemBtn.innerText = 'New Item';
    list.appendChild(newListItemBtn);
    listArea.appendChild(list);
    return newListItemBtn;
}

createListBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    createList();
});

newListItemBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert('hey');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPEhtml>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="createListBtn">Create List</button>
    <div id="listArea">
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that because,

1. variable scope for `newListItemBtn` is available only inside `createList()` function and can't access outside
2. Even if you move `newListItemBtn` variable definition outside, element is not available yet and you will still JS error

Better move `newListItemBtn` event listner inside the `createList()` function

```
 function createList(){
    var list = document.createElement('ul'),
        newListItemBtn = document.createElement('button');

    newListItemBtn.classList.add ('newListItemBtn');
    newListItemBtn.innerText = 'New Item';

    newListItemBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
       alert('hey');
    });    

    list.appendChild(newListItemBtn);
    listArea.appendChild(list);
    return newListItemBtn;
}
```

Comment: Yea that's what I usually do, but it all gets jumbled up, so I was trying to see if there was a more efficient way of writing this code.

Comment: This is a efficient way because if you are creating more than one `newListItemBtn ` element the `clcik` event will attach only to created new element. If you want to move `newListItemBtn` outside then event binding duplication might happen

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```js
var createListBtn = document.getElementById('createListBtn'),
    listArea = document.getElementById('listArea');

function createList(){
    var list = document.createElement('ul'),
        newListItemBtn = document.createElement('button');
    
    newListItemBtn.classList.add ('newListItemBtn');
    newListItemBtn.innerText = 'New Item';
    list.appendChild(newListItemBtn);
    listArea.appendChild(list);
    
    newListItemBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
      alert("hi");
    });
}

createListBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    createList();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPEhtml>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="createListBtn">Create List</button>
    <div id="listArea">
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `click` event listener to your `newListItemBtn` in the same scope you declared it in (in your `creatList()` function).